# как поставить ограничения на загрузку фотографий в контеинер

Tags: javascript, jquery

проблема в том что в контаинер нужно загружать максимум 10 блоков  те фото которые закидывает после 11 и тд не создавать
html:

```
<div class="info__row gallery" id="galleryUpload"></div>
```

js:

```
var files,
                    nameArr = new Array(),
                    j = 1;
                function handleFileSelect(evt) {
                    files = evt.target.files;
                    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                        if(f.size < (2*1024*1024)){
                            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                                alert("Image only please....");
                            }
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                                    return function (e) {
                                        $("#galleryUpload").append("<div class='photo'><img src='" + e.target.result + "' title='" + escape(theFile.name) + "'><span class='fa fa-times' data-button='delete_image'></span></div>");
                                    };
                            })(f);
                            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
                        }
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById('add_photo').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставь перед рендером проверку на число которое в переменной i, if (i > 9), остонавливай выполнение при, else рендери блоки.